# setlinearvelocity don't change speed with large vec

Tags: box2d

I find that it give const speed for difference value upon 100 to 10000. It don't faster then little one. I want a fast instant speed on the screen.

Comment: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas

Comment: b2Settings.h You can change the value (b2_maxTranslation) if you need to, just be aware that the values in this file are tuned to work well together so you may get other problems if you change it too much.